# biblatex: change which fields are printed for different entry types in the preamble

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I wish to print the `url` field using the `authoryear` style but only for `@MISC` entry types.

My hacky solution is to set `style=authoryear, url=false` in the package options, and set the `title` field equal to `url` for `@MISC` entries. This is OK for me in this particular case, because the `title` of the `@MISC` entries are not important, but I would like to know whether there is a better way to do this.

The `url` -> `title` is achieved through the following preamble code

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \pertype{misc}
            \step[fieldsource=url]
            \step[fieldset=title, origfieldval]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 0. Use `@online` instead of `@misc`

The `@online` entry type always shows the `url` field regardless of the global `url` option setting.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, url=false]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{bronto,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1972-11-16},
  url     = {http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  urldate = {2015-09-07},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{bronto}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### 1. Set the `url` option per type (`biblatex` 3.15 and above)

Since `biblatex` 3.15 you can set the `url` option per type in the standard styles (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1000), so you can disable `url` globally, but reenable it for `@misc`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, url=false]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[misc]{url=true}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{bronto,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1972-11-16},
  url     = {http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  urldate = {2015-09-07},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{bronto}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### 2. Delete the `url` field with a sourcemap

This solution does not use the `url` option. Instead it deletes the `url` and `urldate` fields for all types except `@misc` with a sourcemap.

The advantage is that the field is really gone for good and is not used to generate label data (for example the label date).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pernottype{misc}
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{bronto,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1972-11-16},
  url     = {http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  urldate = {2015-09-07},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{bronto}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

In all cases the output will be

[image: Elk, Anne (16th Nov. 1972). Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses. url: http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf (visited on 07/09/2015).]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! BTW, is your last solution equivalent to `\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{misc}{}{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{urldate}}}` ?

Comment: @Enredanrestos Not exactly. The sourcemap clears out the data before it even reaches `biblatex`. `\AtEveryBibitem` & `\clearfield` only clear the data at the last minute when the bibliography entry is printed. Often that results in the same output, but in case of `urldate` this has implications for `labeldate` generation. If `urldate` is cleared with a sourcemap it is definitely not seen, if `\clearfield` is used, it is still used. Generally I recommend getting rid of unwanted data as early as possible (so with a sourcemap rather than `\clearfield`) or suppress printing via options.